# Error while opening Firefox with Selenium in Ubuntu

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver, selenium3

I'm using Selenium 3 on Ubuntu and I am not able to launch the Firefox browser itself. I am getting following error-

**error**:

```
"driver is not executable"...
```

Here is the script:

```
package pom;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Demo2
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty(
          "webdriver.gecko.driver",
          "/home/chetan/workspace/Test_Project/driverfiles/geckodriver");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the capabilities set before running your script. There is a version compatibility issue going around.

Be clear on what you want. I know it would be difficult to adjust with stack community but make sure you learn quicker.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/path/to/your/geckodriver);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("your link");
```

Comment: quicker than what? ;)

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux OS files need to be marked as executable, probably you downloaded driver manually and didn't set the executable flag, try the following command:

```
chmod +x driverFilename
```

For GUI methods look at [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-termina) for alternatives.